# If $U$ is a closed subgroup of $GL(V)$ consisting of unipotent elements, show that $\log x$ belongs to $\mathfrak{u}$

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

> If $U$ is a closed subgroup of $GL(V)$ consisting of unipotent elements, show that $\log x$ $(x \in U)$ belongs to $\mathfrak{u}$.

Here, for an unipotent element $x \in GL(V)$, $\log x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+1}(x-1)^i/ i$. $\mathfrak{u}$ is the Lie algebra of $U$. All can be represented in matrix form.

If I am not mistaken, $x$ can be transformed into a triangular matrix with diagonal elements all equal $1$. So $T_{ij}$ $(1 \leq j < i \leq n)$, $T_{kk}$ $(1 \leq k \leq n)$ are all in $\mathscr{I}(U)$, the defining ideal of $U$. Suppose that $\mathrm{dim}V = n$, then every element of $y \in U$, satisfies $(y -1)^n =1$. Then how can I find a polynomial $f(T_{11}, \cdots, T_{nn}) \in \mathscr{I}(U)$, according to the equality $(y -1)^n =1$? I think this might be helpful for the proof.

Then, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x \in U$ is [unipotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent), by its very definition it means that $x-1$ is nilpotent, i.e. $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $(x-1)^k = 0$ $\forall k \ge n$.

The defining series for $\log(x)$ then becomes a polynomial of order $\le n$.

What you need to show is that $(x-1)^k \in \mathfrak{u}$ for $1 \le k < n$, then $\log(x) \in \mathfrak{u}$, because $\mathfrak{u}$ is a linear space.

It is easy to see that $\exp( (x-1)^k )$ is unipotent, and $(x-1)^k \in \mathfrak{u}$. Indeed:
$$
  \exp( (x-1)^k ) - 1 = (x-1)^k \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^k + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} (x-1)^{(n-1) k} \right)
$$ 
Hence $\left(\exp( (x-1)^k ) - 1\right)^n = (x-1)^{n k} \left( 1 + \ldots \right)^n = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But would you please allow me to give out one more question? Why do the unipotency of $\exp( (x-1)^k )$ imply that $(x-1)^k \in \mathfrak{u}$ ? I am sorry but this point is still unclear to me.

Comment: Exponentiation of Lie algebra elements gives elements of $U$ by definition. I think the closedness of $U$ somehow implies that any element, whose exponential is in $U$ must be from $\mathfrak{u}$

Comment: Would you please give me a reference on "exponentiation of Lie algebra elements gives elements of $U$ by definition"? On the book I am reading, Lie algebra of an algebraic group is defined to be the algbebra of left invariant derivations of this group. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShinyaSakai Any Lie algebra element gives rise to [one-parameter subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_group). See also the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) page.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I still don't know some elementary facts. As you have said "the closedness of $U$ somehow implies that any element, whose exponential is in $U$ must be from $\mathfrak{u}$". I see that $\exp ((x-1)^k)$ is unipotent, but why must it be in $U$? (Then we can infer that $(x-1)^k \in \mathfrak{u}$.)  Moreover, when $G$ is an algebraic group of unipotent elements, is it true that $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G$ and $\log: G \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ are both bijections? I sincerely wish to get your answer if it won't take you too much trouble.

Comment: @ShinyaSakai Did you ever sort this out? I have the same question... I am doubtful of Sasha's assertion that the exponential of a Lie algebra element always gives an element of $U$ in cases besides $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. I have asked essentially this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642360/748775)